# Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at a. Prove $f \circ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $f(a)$.

Tags: proof-writing

I am having a bit of difficulty with this proof.

I know $|x-a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$.

I know $f$ is only continuous at a, so do I need to prove f is continuous at $f(a)$ before moving on with the proof? If yes, I'm not sure how.

I have the first line $|f(x) - f(f(a))|$, but I'm not sure how to prove, in a general sense, how this is continuous.

Even bypassing proving the f(f(a)) continuity, the bulk of the problem is still an issue: Proving $|x-a| \implies f(f(x)) - f(f(a)) < \epsilon$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I understand that you define $f\cdot f$ as the composition $f· f(x) = f(f(x))$?
Hint: what if you replace $x$ by $f(x)$ and $a$ by $f(a)$ in your first equation ;)

Comment: In general you will need to use continuity of $f$ at all points of the domain, to show the composition of $f$ with itself is continuous at all points of the domain.  Why do you say "I know $f$ is only continuous at $a$"?

Comment: @hardmath My apologies, I left that condition out of the original question. As it was given to me, f is only defined at a.

Comment: $f$ is only defined on the point $a$ ? Are you sure ? Then $|f(f(a))-f(f(a))| = 0$ ...

Comment: There is a big difference between saying $f$ is only *defined* at $a$ and saying it is only *continuous* at $a$.  In any case, if $f$ is only defined at $a$, then the composition of $f$ with itself is not defined unless $f(a) = a$.  A function defined only at one point is not really very interesting from the standpoint of continuity there.

Comment: Are you sure $f\cdot f(x)$ is not $f(x)f(x)$ ?

Comment: Indeed, we're talking about $f\cdot f = f^2$, not the composition. You would need an assumption about continuity at $f(a)$, as you surmised, to do something with $f\circ f$.

Answer (score 1):

The statement doesn't hold always...

See the example $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$:
$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}  x+2 &\text { when }x\in (-\infty,4) \\ 10 &\text {  when  }x\in [4,\infty] \end{cases} $$
Then: 
$$ (f\circ f)(x) = \begin{cases} x+4 &\text { when  }x\in (-\infty,2) \\ 10 &\text{ when } x\in [2,\infty]\end{cases} $$
Clearly $f $ is continuous at $2$, but $f\circ f$ is not continuous at $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Some notes to help the OP sort out what the real problem is (to be deleted once the Question is appropriately clarified).

If $f$ were only *defined* at $x=a$, it would not make much sense to speak of it being continuous.  The definition of continuity at $x=a$ calls for $f$ to be defined on a *deleted neighborhood* of $a$.

Furthermore if $f(f(a))$ is defined, then $f(a)$ has to belong to the domain of $f$.  Unless we knew $f$ was continuous at $f(a)$ as well as at $x=a$, we would have no reason to expect $f\circ f$ to be continuous at $x=a$.  Counterexamples are easily constructed.

Possibly $f\cdot f$ is the *product* of $f$ with itself.  In this case, as @LL3.14 suggests, $f$ could be defined everywhere and $f\cdot f$ would be defined everywhere (on the real numbers), and continuity of $f$ at $x=a$ would imply continuity of $f\cdot f$ at $x=a$.